# Firestore does not fetch previous data after re-install

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I'm using Firebase Cloud Firestore with Firestore UI RecyclerView to display items on `MainActivity`. Everything works fine except that, when I uninstall and re-install the app, `query` does not fetch previously added items and only an empty list appears. When I add a new item to Firestore after re-install, only that item is fetched and still no previous data. However, I can see both previously added data and the new item on Firebase Console.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue or any idea what can cause this?

My function that sets up the `RecyclerView` is as follows. I call this function and then call `adapter.startListening()` in `onStart` and `adapter.stopListening()` in `onStop`.

```
private void setupRecyclerView() {
    if(shouldStartSignIn()) return;
    if(!PermissionUtils.requestPermission(this, RC_STORAGE_PERMISSION, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Permission not granted, don't continue");
        return;
    }
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    pagesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(Page.COLLECTION).whereEqualTo(Page.FIELD_USER_ID, FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).orderBy(Page.FIELD_TIMESTAMP).limit(50);
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Page> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Page>().setQuery(query, Page.class).build();
    adapter = new PagesAdapter(options, this);

    pagesRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Can you share your security rules? And check LogCat for errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized your`query` but the query is not attached to any listener which actually pulls the data. So your adapter is empty. Basically you need to do something like this:

```
query.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
  @Override
  public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot snapshot,
                    @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
      if (e != null) {
          // Handle error
          //...
          return;
      }

      // Convert query snapshot to a list of chats
      List<Chat> chats = snapshot.toObjects(Chat.class);

      // Update UI
      // ...
  }
});
```

You can read more about it here: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/firestore#querying

Comment: I'm using [FirebaseUI library](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/firestore), which provides `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` with a built-in listener. So, I just need to call `adapter.startListening()` to trigger that listener according to `readme.md` page of that repository.

Comment: I have updated the code snippet and the link, hope that helps